# Background image not correctly sizing to screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `background-size: contain;` to set my background img size, but it instead creates a bunch of small images of my background and tiles them across the screen. If I use some other sizing properties parts of the image get cut off. I've also tried `background-size: 100% 100%` to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <title>The Bucker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="/pricing.html">Pricing</a>
      <a href="/about.html">About</a>
      <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div> 

<!-- page content in this div to push page content to the right  -->
    <div id="main">
      <body>
        <title>TheBucker</title>
        <a onclick="openNav()">
          <img id="icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/menu.png" alt="menu_icon">
        </a>
        <!-- <img id="yank" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/83169c5c-c88c-4abb-a1a3-fbaea805258a%2Fcannabis%203_nobck.png?v=1586549582037" alt="if you're seeing this, just wait or reload the page"> -->

        <script>
        /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
          function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
          }

          /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
          function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
          } 
        </script>
      </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Here is my `style.css`

```
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/83169c5c-c88c-4abb-a1a3-fbaea805258a%2Fbackground_no_text.jpg?v=1586547217919");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `background-repeat: no-repeat;` or `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen this displays the whole image except it is now super small in the top right of the screen. If I use cover instead of contain it returns to the normal size, except the bottom part is still cut off, the section I am trying to fix from being cut off.

Comment: `contain` displays your whole image, `cover` fill out the block. You can adjust which part is visible when using `cover` with `background-position`, though.

Comment: I've used both `contain` and `cover` with your suggestions and the image does not cover. `contain` displays the whole image except it is really small in the top, center. `cover` cuts off the top half of the image and only covers half of the screen with the bottom.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do, exactly?

Comment: I just want the image to fit to the background without any of it being cut off. It doesn't seem like it should be hard to do, but none of the background properties correctly fit it. @chriskirknielsen

Comment: That's exactly what `contain` does. The background will fit without removing any parts of the image, but might leave empty space around it.

Comment: yes, and like i said in a previous comment, `contain` tiles the image with no empty space. if I use `no-repeat`, it leaves me with a small tile of the image. @chriskirknielsen

Answer (score 2):

Try to use backgroud-size cover or 100%, remove background repeat and set background-position center like this:

```css
body {
      font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      background-image: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/83169c5c-c88c-4abb-a1a3-fbaea805258a%2Fbackground_no_text.jpg?v=1586547217919");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<body>

   <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="/pricing.html">Pricing</a>
      <a href="/about.html">About</a>
      <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: @EthanOnweller added a snippet for you how it looks like

Comment: switched up my `<body>` tags to be outside of the `<div>` and added the styling properties, still not working. Its just a zoomed in portion of the image.

Comment: Then explain a bit more what exacltly needs to be done.

Comment: The image just needs to cover the background completely. If I just use `background-size: cover` without any other modifications a little bit of the top and bottom of the image are cut off. Adding the rest of the property modifications messes it up even more. @ElmanHuseynov

Comment: @EthanOnweller it will cut off if you use background-size: cover property, because it zoomes image to fill all screen, by choosing position you can just adjust a bit the view port of image (top, center and etc). The other way is to put another image, maybe then it will looks better.

Comment: using the center, top, etc modifiers don't fix it, parts of the image are still cut off. I've tried multiple images and they are still being cut off. thank you for you help though. @ElmanHuseynov

Comment: @EthanOnweller want to mention again, it can maybe cut off if the image proportion are not equal the screen viewport.